# Failed to getEnergyData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I am getting this error and also "Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent " error when i'm connecting my device using cable and i also enable usb debugging. Android studio is showing my account but still i cannot use my device anyone please help me.

I have tried by checking and updating my sdk and also by removing my cable and attaching it again